# SQL Server 2005 - DataType of variable to store a RowSet

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, sqldatatypes, sql-in

In a typical stored procedure i am working there are various checks with the same query as below.

```
SELECT ... FROM Projects WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT ProjectId FROM Tasks)
```

i would like to replace the query `(SELECT ProjectId FROM Tasks)` with a `variable` but am confused as to what `datatype` it has to be. **Do you know**? also caching this result is detrimental or is there easier way to doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may cteate table typed variable and use it multiple times, like that:

```
CREATE @Projects TABLE(Id INT NOT NULL)

INSERT @Projects SELECT ProjectId FROM Tasks

SELECT ... FROM Projects WHERE ProjectId IN (SELECT ProjectId FROM @Projects)
SELECT ... FROM Projects WHERE ProjectId NOT IN (SELECT ProjectId FROM @Projects)
```

Althought - it is not **replacement** of query by variable, it is make more reusable the subquery results

**But**

under certain conditions this may degrade your queries' performance

Comment: what certain conditions? can u add a few

Comment: If you'll use it just one time or amount of rows relatively bit - better create temp table with indexes instead of table variable. Sql Server does not creates statistics on table variables and does it ot temp tables - so, temp tables may outperform the table vars

Answer (score 1):

This form is preferable (although optimiser should perform this optimisation):

```
SELECT ... FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Tasks t ON t.ProjectID = p.ProjectId
```

Then add the condition as a WHERE clause (instead of performing the inner select and attempting to place a list of ProjectId's in a variable):

```
SELECT ... FROM Projects p
INNER JOIN Tasks t ON t.ProjectID = p.ProjectId
WHERE someCondtionOnTasksTable
```